# How to stop a specific Job in quartz scheduler

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler

How to stop a specific Job in quartz scheduler I had read multiple similar question but most of the questions don't have an answer and the ones that Have one are outdated and refers to a documentation that no longer exist

The response in most of the questions are that this `You need to write a your job as an implementation of InterruptableJob. To interrupt this job, you need handle to Scheduler, and call interrupt(jobKey<<job name & job group>>)` and the point to this dead link http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.0.0/org/quartz/InterruptableJob.html

But does anyone have an example of how to do this

Answer (score 1):

You can find an explanation here: http://forums.terracotta.org/forums/posts/list/7700.page

The relevant part is:

```
 public void interrupt() throws UnableToInterruptJobException
 {
     stopFlag.set(true);
     Thread thread = workerThread.getAndSet(null);
     if (thread != null)
         thread.interrupt();
 }
```

And you can call it like this:

```
 SchedulerFactory schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
 Scheduler scheduler = schedulerFactory.getScheduler();
 List<JobExecutionContext> currentlyExecuting = scheduler.getCurrentlyExecutingJobs();

 for( JobExecutionContext jobExecutionContext : currentlyExecuting)
 {
      if( jobExecutionContext.getJobDetail().getKey().getName().equals( "Name"))
      {
            scheduler.interrupt( jobExecutionContext.getJobDetail().getKey());
      }
 }
```

Comment: Hi @uoyilmaz, I have the similar issue. what is the workerThread here.